# ValueError : " invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,119' " how to solve?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to change from object to int64
but I got this error message, how can i solve this issue?

---

df.head()

[image: screenshot]

df.info()

[image: screenshot]

df_int = df['상담신청 유저획득 단가'].astype(int)

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,119'

Comment: Try `'df['col'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '').astype(int)` and check if its working

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd column is of type `object`, meaning it is not an integer because it has a comma in it. You can treat the type `object` as type `string` or convert it to string, and remove the comma using the `str.replace(",","")` syntax, and then convert the string to integer.